# AR mode doesn't find Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

When I find a wild Pokemon, it shows in the app but when I set AR on, it doesn't show anymore. I can catch it only when the AR is off and I cannot take real world pictures with the pokemon. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking around?

Comment: Jinx, when you turn the AR mode back on, do you see weird symbols to the sides of the screen?

Comment: I have a friend who have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I've tried looking around (turning, going down etc) but maybe I'm doing it wrong, don't know. There are no symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the phone you have.

I have a Sony C4, and the same problems occurs for me. So I have to play without the AR mode, it's not really embarrassing and the game is still awesome.

The problem is the gyroscope. This little thing controlled by the accelerometer, will make the Pokémon appear in AR mode.

Here is the link to the App (Play Store) to check if you do have a gyroscope or if you don't. [Sensor Kinetics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innoventions.sensorkinetics)

If you want to know a bit more, here's the [reddit source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rlfwk/ar_mode_not_working/).

Hope it helps.